# kubuntu 18.10 swapfile

Tags: kubuntu

Kubuntu 10 sends me the following message:

```
bash: / : est un dossier
bash: /swapfile: Permission non accordée
```

etc/fstab :

```
#                
# / was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=72a4ea19-d9ab-4448-ae8d-f27c71314d38   /   ext4   errors=remount-ro   0    1
/swapfile                                 none  swap    sw                 0    0
```

How to correct?

cordially

Comment: What is the output of `cat /proc/swaps`? Add that to your question. Also, when do you get those messages and where do you find them? Are you executing a command...?

Comment: I receive the message at the opening of Konsole, without executing command.
I configured 1 administrator account and 2 user accounts.

Comment: $ cat /proc/swaps

Comment: Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile                               file            2097148 0       -2

Comment: Please add the extra information to your original question by editing.

Answer (score 0):

I receive the message at the opening of Konsole, without executing command.
I configured 1 administrator account and 2 user accounts.

```
bash: / : est un dossier
bash: /swapfile: Permission non accordée
xxxx@Zalman:~$ cat /proc/swaps
Filename                    Type            Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile                  file            2097148 41968   -2
xxxx@Zalman:~$
```